# Only iOS native Facebook login working

Tags: facebook, ios6

I've implemented the Facebook sdk 3.2 into my ios app. I want to use it to identify the user and use his basic information. I based my code on the "HelloFacebookSample" that comes with the SDK.
Everything seemed to be working fine until I noticed that login functionality only works with the iOS build in fb account management. When I have no FB account in my settings my app opens safari I login and approve the app, all seems ok but when the app comes back I show as logged out. I've triple checked my apps code with the sample and can't find a difference so I'm wondering if the issue could be within the app setup on the fb website ?

I'd appreciate any clues that could point me in the direction of a solution ;)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :D
I was missing the following method in my app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```